# CSS Div Height setting with Dynamic Content with inner DIV

Tags: html, css

CSS Code :

```
 .modal {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 4;
    /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px;
    /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    /*  overflow: auto; Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal outer div*/

.modal-content {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 56%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 70%
}

/* inner div */

.modal-content1 {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1.5%;
    /* border: 1px solid #888;   */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 83%
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<!-- The Modal to create flash background with z-index-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Div to hold close button and  Acknowledge button which should act as window without scroll-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <!-- close button -->
        <!-- div to hold actual dynamic content which requires scroll -->
        <div class="modal-content1">
            MY DYNAMIC CONTENT GOES HERE
        </div>
        <!-- Acknowledge button -->
        Acknowledge button will code will be placed here
    </div>
</div>
```

In **modal-content1**(inner div) css class I have added overflow property but still I am not able to get scroll bar in inner div which uses same modal-content1.

**Note :** scroll will appear if i set height: values in px instead of **auto** in **modal-content**(outer div) and I need both div expand and shrink based on content so i don't want to have height property in px (pixels).

How can I get scroll bar only for inner div maintaining out div expands while inner div expand based on content?

To be clear about my design, I am trying to create window with content inside with buttons and so I need scroll only for content not buttons. Hence our div will contain buttons and inner div which will have dynamic contents.

Comment: but if you set `height:auto` you will never need scroll because the modal be `auto` means the `height` as the content inside without limit

Comment: you can simply set the bottons `fixed` to bottom of modal

Comment: Do you have a URL to see this in action, so I can help better?

Comment: @Adesh shetty you must set `height` with `px` if you want scroll

Comment: @לבנימלכה setting height:auto with max-height:70% will enable scroll . but my prob here is outer div is it has auto then inner div doesnot show scroll

Comment: @Invariant Change im just including this page along with my home page . if you could help me understand how we can make both div expand based on dynamic contend if u can suggest design way also fine for me .

Comment: Change the `height: auto` in `modal-content` to `height: 100%`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want scrollbars you are going to have to define a height value other than auto for your parent containers. Even using percentages for all containers will be fine as long as the child you want to be scrollable is less than 100%. This should work for you:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .modal {
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 4; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height:100%; /* Full height */
    /*  overflow: auto; Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }


  /* Modal outer div*/
  .modal-content {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888; 
    width: 56%;
    height: auto;   
    height:100%

  }
  /* inner div */
  .modal-content1 {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1.5%;  
    /* border: 1px solid #888;   */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    height:50%

  }
</style>


<!-- The Modal to create flash background with z-index-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal"> 
  <!-- Div to hold close button and  Acknowledge button which should act as window without scroll-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span> <!-- close button -->   
    <!-- div to hold actual dynamic content which requires scroll -->
    <div class="modal-content1"> 
      <h1>
        content
      </h1>
      data<br><br><br>
      <h1>
        content
      </h1>
      data<br><br><br>
      <h1>
        content
      </h1>
      data<br><br><br>
    </div> 
    <!-- Acknowledge button -->
    Acknowledge button will code will be placed here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you i appreciate your effort and i got the solution  by adding `max-height:460px;` line to  **modal-content1** while still maintaining height:auto property